# RenderLink and custom attribute, space is converted to plus-sign

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

Using Glass mapper Im trying to create an editable link property doing the following using razor and MVC:

```
@(RenderLink(
  x => x.Settings.First().CompanyLink,
  new { @class="navbar-brand page-scroll" },
  true
)))
```

However.. for some reason the two css-classes gets concated with a plus sign between them..
so the end result of the class-attributes value is "navbar-brand+page-scroll"..
Just as an ugly work-around I was hoping that:

```
@(RenderLink(
  x => x.Settings.First().CompanyLink,
  new { @class="navbar-brand page-scroll" },
  true
).ToHtmlString().Replace("+", " ")))
```

Would solve it.. and it kind of did.. but as soon as you edit the link and the page updates, the classes gets concated again.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

this looks like it might be a bug. I will investigate and get back to you.

Mike

Comment: Thanks :), and even more thanks for an awesome work with Glass .. makes my "life" easier :).

Comment: I have tested against the latest release an I don't have the problem. I am using MVC 5.

Comment: Ok, strange.. I downloaded it from NuGet this monday.. any updates since then?.. my version of Glass.Mapper.Sc.Mvc is 3.2.1.42 and its the "Glass mapper MVC-5" nuget package.

Comment: for instance this:
@Editable(x => x.Link, new { @class = "page-scroll btn btn-xl" })
results in this:
<a class="page-scroll+btn+btn-xl scEnabledChrome" title="Tell Me More" sc-part-of="field" style="text-decoration: none;">Tell Me More</a>

Where x.Link is a property of type Link and the Field is of type General Link

Comment: I will paste my test in later.

Comment: I'm getting the same error in a Sitecore 7.2 site with Glass.Mapper.Sc 4.0.1.8, but only if I use the RenderLink method. The Editable method works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a helper class for Razor / Glass so you can add HTML elements. It could work as a different option for adding your css classes.

See blog here: http://mikerobbins.co.uk/2015/07/29/sitecore-razor-glass-attribute-helper-methods-fluent-api/

You can use the helper like this:

```
@(RenderLink(x => x.Settings.First().CompanyLink,new HtmlAttributes().CssClass("navbar-brand page-scroll").Render())
```